# How to show and hide the content based on dropdown selection items in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

My requirement is to show the content based on selection of dropdown list.

**component.ts**

```
OptionList: LookupActionCode[]=[];
public setList(actionType: any):void{
  this.anotherOptionList = [];
   if(actionType == dataConstant.calendar){
  this.List.push(
       {
          
          Name: dataConstant.content
       },
      {
       Name: dataConstant.showcontent
      },
 {
  Name: dataConstant.hidecontent
       },
   )}

 switch(actionType){
    case dataConstant.memberdata:
      this.OptionList = this.memberCodes;
      break;
      case dataConstant.referral:
        this.OptionList= this.optionalCodes;
      break;
     
      case dataConstant.Calendar:
        this.OptionList = this.List;
        break;
     }
```

**.component.html**

```
//first dropdown
<label for="OptionList" class="cpp-required"> <b>Action</b></label>
 <select id=action class="form-control"  required  (change) ="setList($event.target.value)">
               <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
             <option [value] = "dataConstant.referral">{{dataConstant.referral}}</option>
 <option [value] = "dataConstant.memberdata">{{dataConstant.memberdata}}</option>
 <option [value] = "dataConstant.calendar">{{dataConstant.content}}</option>
             </select>    
//second dropdown


<label> <b>Action</b></label>
 <select id=action class="form-control"  required>
               <option value="" disabled [selected]="true"></option>
               <option *ngFor="let option of optionList" [value] ="option">{{option.Name}} </option>
             </select>   

<div *ngIf="logic>
//some content to show and hide the  data
        </div>
```

So my requirement is from the first dropdown if i select the dataConstant.content then In secondit will show the realted dropdown lists those are dataConstant.content,dataConstant.showcontent and dataConstant.showcontent (implemented)
So If select the dataConstant.showcontent value then I need to show the data in div

Can anyone help me on this

Answer (score 0):

If you first add a property to your component in ts to hold the selected value:

```
theProperty: string | undefined;
```

and on your select list in html add:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="theProperty" ect...
```

This will set up two way binding between your property and the select list. (Note reactive forms are good option here but have chose this for simplicity).

You can then add:

```
*ngIf="theProperty === thingToMatchTo"
```

But maybe pick a more sensible property name than what I've used.

NOTE - Make sure you add `FormsModule` to your imports in the Module that this component is declared. It's what makes the ngModel directive available to you.

Comment: I did the same but not working

Comment: could you please edit the above with my requirement then it would be helpful for me